# how to center quote icon with lines separated

Tags: html, css

I need to code this thing in css, so I am kind of stuck.

[image]

And my code looks like this:

```
      .quotation {
        @extend .col-lg-12;
        color:#d8b063;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 1px solid #d8b063;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d8b063;
        padding: 50px 0;
        margin-bottom: 48px;


        blockquote {
          font-size: 22px;
          font-family: "Georgia", sans-serif;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          border: 0;
        }
        
        p {
          font-size: 17px;
          margin-top: 27px;
         }
        
      }
    <div class="quotation">
    <img><img src="/assets/quote.png" alt="Quote sign" /></img>
    <blockquote>The tipping point is that magic moment when an idea, trend, or social behavior crosses a threshold, tips, and spreads like wildfire.<p>Malcolm Gladwell</p></blockquote>
    </div>
```

I have a problem how to pull back icon back so its centered on first line and separated from lines. 
I guess I can do that for example with margin: -120px, but I don't now how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the `pseudo-element` `before`?

```
quotation {
    @extend .col-lg-12;
    color:#d8b063;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8b063;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8b063;
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin-bottom: 48px;


    .quotation:before {
      content: url("/assets/quote.png");
      display: inline-block;
      height: 22px;
    }
    ...

  }
```